# Proper image ratio scaling

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a script that I use to scale member profile images, I was wondering what is the proper way to perform scaling for profile pictures without distorting the images native ratio too much. What is the logic behind keeping the images aspect ratio when uploading?Currently I use this  bit of code to perform my scaling

```
//SCALING IMAGES 
    $newwidth = 301;
    $newheight = ceil(($height/$width)*$newwidth);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up example to set image resample size:

```
class imagemanipulate
{
public function set_size($max_x = 100,$max_y = 100)
{

    // Resize
    if($this->x_input > $max_x || $this->y_input > $max_y)
    {

    $a= $max_x / $max_y;
    $b= $this->x_input / $this->y_input;

    if ($a<$b)
    {

        $this->x_output = $max_x;
        $this->y_output = ($max_x / $this->x_input) * $this->y_input;

    }
    else
    {

        $this->y_output = $max_y;
        $this->x_output = ($max_y / $this->y_input) * $this->x_input;

    }
    // Ready

    $this->resize = TRUE;

    }

    // Don't resize       
    else { $this->resize = FALSE; }

}
 }


 $inst = new imagemanipulate;
 $inst->set_size('301', '301');

 $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($inst->x_output,$inst->y_output);


 imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$inst->x_output,$inst->y_output,$width,$height);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but in your answer where is $this->x_input defined?

Comment: max_x and max_y represents the max width and height I would want the picture to be, or is it a default fall back value?

Comment: As it stands, this didn't work out for me. Invalid image dimensions error thrown for the `$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($inst->x_output,$inst->y_output);`